# How to send a mail to all the domains without configuring mail server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to send a mail to any domains(gmail,yahoo) without configuring any mail servers in environment.rb.
Is it possible? if it's NO the how devise_invitable gem is allowing us to trigger the mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use third party email services like:

http://sendgrid.com/

http://www.mailgun.com/

http://aws.amazon.com/ses/

Though you will still need to specify those in environment files, just that you won't need to manage an email server.